# return list while keeping only items in sublist on condition C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have the following object:

```
public class Model
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    public List<Characteristic> Characteristics{ get; set; }
    public List<Size> Sizes{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<Model> models` I'm dealing with. I want to filter it out with a condition on `Sizes` , in a way that :

Eventually I want to keep the ID, Price, Address, Characteristics in the `List<Model> models`, but in `List<Size> Sizes` I keep only the items that match the condition on `Sizes`.

In linQ, there is a way to keep the items in `models` where **ALL** the items in `Sizes` match a condition :

```
 var keep = models.Where(r => r.Sizes.All(x => x > condition)).ToList();
```

Or  keep the items in `models` where **AT LEAST ONE OF** the items in `Sizes` match a condition :

```
var keep = models.Where(r => r.Sizes.Any(x => x > condition)).ToList();
```

What I want is, to keep models, and in it **keep the Sizes that ONLY match a condition.**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Then what you want to do is loop over the models and mutate them by filtering the `Sizes`.

Answer (score 1):

That would mutate your models, so for that you should loop over them. Then you can use Linq to filter the `Sizes`.

```
foreach(var m in models)
{
    m.Sizes = m.Sizes.Where(x => x > condition).ToList();
}
```

If you don't want to mutate your original models then you'd have to create new ones.

```
var keep = models.Select(m => new Model {
    ID = m.ID,
    Price = m.Price,
    Address = m.Address,
    Characteristics = m.Characteristics,
    Sizes = m.Sizes.Where(x => x > condition).ToList()
});
```

Comment: It worked but missing a line of code that I added for you. Please accept my edit so I can verify it as the correct answer.